# C# Unit Tests: Forcing the running/compiling of a WcfRest Service when testing a MVC site? Currently debug points are NOT hit in Rest Service

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing

I have a few tests which test my controllers in an MVC app. Everything seems to be ok but then when i call my rest service from within a controller the debug points are not hit in the rest service.

Is there a solution for this? Apart from the Attach Process or running 2 instances of visual studio, 1 for mvc and 1 for rest?

Thanks

Comment: How is the REST service set up: IIS, WAS, self hosted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the rest service is running in its own process?  Is it on a separate app pool?

Are you looking for "Debugging Multiple Processes"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a404w14b.aspx

As you noted you can always run 2 instances of visual studio ;).